# Checking files against each other for "fraud"

Tags: java, file, math

Yes, this is for a lab I'm doing, but I'm completely lost.

If I have a set of files, all imported by the scanner, with math problems in them. How would I go about checking the files to make sure that they have not been "altered" in the way that "someone" changed the equations for a better grade. (I'm meant to act as a teacher with a grading program to take files from students and automatically grade them)

Like if the problems are usually this

`589 + 66 = 3`
`134 - 49 = 2`
`343 + 24 = 3`
`455 - 92 = 4`

but they were "changed" in a file to be

`1 + 1 = 2`
`1 + 1 = 2`
`1 + 1 = 2`
`1 + 1 = 2`

in order to trick the grading program. How would I check the files against a master file (that just has the problems without the answers like `589 + 66 =`) so that it would be able to notice if the file was altered?

I can't use regex, try/catch, arrays, or systemTokenizers.

Right now, my program runs through the files and prints out how many of the answers in the files are correct

```
SubmissionA 20                       
SubmissionB 17               
SubmissionC 20        
SubmissionD 16
```

However, lets say that submissionC is the one where the student changed the problems to 1+1=2 in order to fool the program. I would like for the program to print:

```
 SubmissionA 20                       
 SubmissionB 17               
 SubmissionC File has been altered!      
 SubmissionD 16
```

Comment: So the result should say `589 + 66 = 3` and you need to compare the part up to the = to see if it matches `589 + 66 =` and you have to do that for every problem?  Are the questions on separate lines? Or are they all on one line like you are showing them?

Comment: They are all on separate lines. And yes, I have to check every problem against a "master" file.

Comment: Maybe a short snippet of an example run of the program, and of the test and what you expect the program to achieve and results for a true outcome and false outcome. You question is very unclear

Answer (score 2):

As you're are going through the file collecting correct answers, simultaneously go through the master file. For each correct answer, compare the line (or equation as appropriate) to the matching master entry, and flag those that differ.

Basically, whereas before you had a single check for the "correct answer" (i.e. does the answer match), now you have two checks (does the answer match, and do the equation match).

Addenda:

I don't know your current program. I don't know your input formats. So, this is all assumption.

Somehow, you have a list of the correct answers. And somehow, you have a list of test answers. You've demonstrated that you can compare the correct answers to the test answers.

All of your representations are of full equations (`1 + 1 = 2`), but it's not clear how you're getting the answer value from the submitted answer text. But, assuming that you are doing that, and that the correct answer is also represented as `589 + 66 = 655`, i.e. the same format as the submitted answers, then if you're able extract the answer value from `1 + 1 = 2`, then you should be capable of extracting the correct answer value from `589 + 66 = 655` in a similar way.

If you are able to extract the respective answers, then using the same technique, you should be able to extract the question as well. That is, from `1 + 1 = 2` you should be able to extract both `1 + 1 =` and `2`.

So, what you do when grading the answers, is you read BOTH files, the correct answer key, and the submitted answers, at the same time.

For example:

```
File correctAnswers = new File("correctanswers.txt");
File testAnswers = new File("testanswers.txt");

BufferedReader correctReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(correctAnswers));
BufferedReader testReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(testAnswers));

String correctLine = correctReader.readLine();
String testLine = testReader.readLine();

while(correctLine != null) {
    if (testLine == null) {
        System.out.println("Bad Test, there are too few test lines.");
        break;
    }
    String correctEquation = getEquation(correctLine);
    String correctAnswer = getAnswer(correctLine);
    String testEquation = getEquation(testLine);
    String testAnswer = getAnswer(testLine);
    if (correctEquation.equals(testEquation)) {
        if (correctAnswer.equals(testAnswer)) {
            correctAnswers = correctAnswers + 1;
        } else {
            wrongAnswers = wrongAnswers + 1;
        }
    } else {
        System.out.println("Bad Test, an equation was tampered with.");
        break;
    }
}
if (testLine != null) {
    System.out.println("Bad Test, there are too many lines in the test.");
}
correctReader.close();
testReader.close();
```

So, hopefully you can see how you scan through both files at the same time, comparing the data as you go. We assume the correct answer file is normative, so if the test file stops to soon, or goes to long, then that's another source of error. Other than that, you're comparing the two parts of the equation for both the correct answer key file and the test file, and iterating along your way.

Comment: Could you possibly show me an example? Or explain it a bit more in depth please? Sorry, I'm just not grasping it yet.

Answer (score 1):

The following code compares two lines of equations for discrepancies.

```
String line1 = input1.nextLine().trim();  // "8 + 2 ="  

                                   // examples from you other deleted post

String line2 = input2.nextLine().trim();  // "1 + 1 = 2"

String line2trim = line2.substring(0, line2.length() - 2)).trim(); // "1 + 1 ="

if (!line1.equals(line2trim)){
    // test is corrupted
}
```

Just loop through the entirety of both files to check for corruption.

**Edit:** Even better approach for answer length greater than one digit e.g. 100

```
String line2trim = line2.substring(0, (line2.indexOf("=") + 1).trim();
```